# change background color of li using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the color of li which contains anchor when the mouse go over it, I make like this

```
 <ul id="SonsItemList">
     <li class="sonItem"><a id="son" href="#" >son 1</a></li>
      <li class="sonItem"><a id="son" href="#" >son 2</a></li>        
 </ul>
```

and jquery is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a#son").hover(function(){
               $("li.sonItem").css("background-color","black");  // it make all li background => black


        });
```

I just want the li that the mous go over to change it's background, how can I make it ?
            });

Comment: Keep id values unique. After all, it's an identification for a specific element.

Comment: Ok, I will make it unique, u r right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need any JavaScript at all.  You can use CSS:

```
li.sonItem:hover 
{
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: @GerManson, which IE versions do u mean?

Comment: @GerManson - Why are you using IE6? http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
$("a[id='son']").hover(function(){
   $(this).closest("li.sonItem").css("background-color","black");  
});
```

**NOTE:** This will work ok, however you should never have more than 1 element with the same id (you can, but it's a very, very bad practice), it'd be better if you use a class, for example `class="son"`, and your selector would be `$("a.son")`.

Cheers

Comment: I have more than one item with the same id, so this way doesn't work too.

Comment: Mi note is only a recommendation. This **will work**, even if you have same ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting a nice hover effect then you'll want jquery, you'll also need jquery-color.js, the code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#menu .dummyclass').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
            }, 50, function () { });
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('#menu .dummyclass').mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: '#000000'
            }, 600, function () { });
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML Markup:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="dummyclass">Home</li>
        <li class="dummyclass">Fixtures</li>
        <li class="dummyclass">Results</li>
        <li class="dummyclass">Tables</li>
        <li class="dummyclass">Constitution</li>
        <li class="dummyclass" style="border-right: none;">Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu ul li .dummyclass {
    /*Dummy class to aid hovering with jQuery*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is unique so dont repeat, u can use in class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".son").hover(function(){
    $(".sonItem").css("background-color","black");
    },function(){
    $(".sonItem").css("background-color","white");
    });
});

<ul id="SonsItemList">
     <li class="sonItem"><a class="son" href="#" >son 1</a></li>
      <li class="sonItem"><a class="son" href="#" >son 2</a></li>        
</ul>
```