# Background color on select checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change background color of li using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918167/change-background-color-of-li-using-jquery)

I'm trying to change background color of li on onselect 'checkbox'.

```
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 1</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 2</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 3</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 4</li>
</ul>
```

I Need to change the whole line background color when some one select checkbox.

[image]

Comment: styling check- or radiobuttons is always pain in the a** ;) I hope with css3 it will be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> <label> Link 1</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> <label> Link 2</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> <label> Link 3</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> <label> Link 4</label></li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS**

```
label{width:150px; display:inline-block}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label{background:blue; color:white}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qgGne/1/)**

For IE you can use a library like **http://selectivizr.com/**

Comment: +1 for css only solution. But, will this work on old browsers?

Comment: unfortunately not for IE. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out i think it will work.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
$('input[type=checkbox]').parent().css('background',''); //This turns all checkboxes background to default
$(this).parent().css('background','red');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).parent().css('background','red');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().css('background','');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/AHrrP/

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 1</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 2</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 3</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 4</li>
</ul>​
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('blue');
        else
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('blue');
    });
});​
```

CSS

```
li {
    padding:4px;
}

li.blue {
    background-color: #08C;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

CSS

```
.highlight{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

I assume you would want the highlight to be gone when the checkbox is re-clicked. here's a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/odezah/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li :checkbox').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background',$(this):is(":checked")?'blue':'');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <ul id="myList">
        <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 3</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /> Link 4</li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myList input').each(function(){
            console.log(this);
                $(this).click(function(){
                console.log(this);
                    if($(this).prop('checked')){
                        $(this).parent().css('background','#eee');
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).parent().css('background','');
                    }
                });
            });             
        });

    </script>
```